# Use ToExpression["variablename"] in Slider

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, slider

I would like to realise something like this (minimial example):

```
a = 2; b = 3;
Row[{Dynamic@ToExpression[#], 
Slider[Dynamic[ToExpression[#]], {1, 5}]}] & /@ {"a", "b"}
```

But the Slider cannot be moved. However, if I change one of the variables ('a=4') then both is updated. I thought I've seen it before but I cannot find it. I tried localising it (With[...]) but that wasn't succesful. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's what you need: [How do you programatically load data into symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this change?:

```
Slider[Dynamic[Evaluate@ToExpression[#, StandardForm, Unevaluated]], {1, 5}]...
```

`Dynamic` is `HoldAll`, so it is not passed a symbol unless `ToExpression` is evaluated first.  But simply sticking in `Evaluate` wouldn't work, because then `a` and `b` would continue to evaluate to their numeric values.  So you can use the third argument of `ToExpression` to suspend evaluation.

But @Kuba's suggestion is even more elegant:

```
Slider[ToExpression[#, StandardForm, Dynamic], {1, 5}]
```

Comment: or: `ToExpression[#, StandardForm, Dynamic]`

Comment: @Kuba Cute.  Much nicer.