# How to generate abstraction clauses programmatically?

Tags: manipulate

I would like to call some complex plotting function, which accepts a list of variables and would like to get sliders for each variable.

Currently I write something like below

```
PlotSines[a_List] := Block[{funcs},
   funcs = Table[Sin[a[[i]] x] + i - 1, {i, 1, Length[a]}];
   Plot[funcs, {x, -5, 5}]
   ];

Manipulate[PlotSines[{a1, a2, a3}], {{a1, 1}, 0.1, 5}, {{a2, 1}, 0.1, 5}, {{a3, 1}, 0.1, 5}]
```

[image]

i.e. explicitly writing each "abstraction" clause of kind `{{a1, 1}, 0.1, 5}`. I name them "abstraction" clauses like in [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), because these clauses "remove" mentioned variable from outer expression.

Now I want to have variable number of a-s and so I can't hardcode expression then.

Can I generate such construction programmatically, so that it generated list of some names, acceptable by `Manipulate` function?

I tried to write this way

```
varlist = Table[Symbol[ToString[StringForm["a``", i]]], {i, 1, 5}]
```

which gave

```
{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}
```

then

```
clauses = Sequence[Table[{{a, 1}, 0.1, 5}, {a, varlist}]]
```

which gave

```
Sequence[{{{a1, 1}, 0.1, 5}, {{a2, 1}, 0.1, 5}, {{a3, 1}, 0.1, 5}, {{a4, 1}, 0.1, 5}, {{a5, 1}, 0.1, 5}}]
```

I was hoping sequnce will "expand" inside manipulate and wrote

```
Manipulate[PlotSines[varlist], clauses]
```

but it complained

```
Manipulate::vsform: Manipulate argument clauses does not have the correct form for a variable specification.
```

**UPDATE**

I thought I should play with evaluation order somehow. I tried to write

```
 Manipulate[PlotSines[varlist], Evaluate[clauses]]
```

but it drew

[image]

apparently `PlotSines` function was executed before `Manipulate` called it

Comment: p.s. related: [How to create symbols from strings and set values for them?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PlotSines[a_List] := 
  Block[{funcs}, 
   funcs = Table[Sin[a[[i]] x] + i - 1, {i, 1, Length[a]}];
   Plot[funcs, {x, -5, 5}]];

foo[n_Integer] := Module[{vars, varSpec},
  vars = Table[Unique["x"], {n}];
  varSpec = Table[{{vars[[i]], 1, StringTemplate["a``"]@i}, 0.1, 5}, {i, 
     Length@vars}];

  Manipulate[
    PlotSines[vars],
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ varSpec]
    ] /. OwnValues[vars]
  ]
```

I am creating unique `xi` because I don't want to care if they already exist. Then I just label them as consecutive `ai` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
varlist = Table[Symbol["a"<>ToString[i]],{i,1,5}];
clauses = Table[{{a,1},0.1,5},{a,varlist}];
manipulate = "Manipulate[PlotSines["<>ToString[varlist]<>"],
    Evaluate[Sequence@@"<>ToString[clauses]<>"]]";
ToExpression[manipulate]
```

Apparently `Manipulate` will automatically hold all of its elements in unevaluated form, but that makes this specific problem a bit tricky to solve. The easiest method I've seen to deal with the holds is to write the command in full as a string and then execute it.

Comment: This will fail if e,g, a1 = 2; was evaluated or any of ai have value

Answer (score 1):

I found a way without string coding:

```
PlotSines[a_List] := Block[{funcs},
   funcs = Table[Sin[a[[i]] x] + i - 1, {i, 1, Length[a]}];
   Plot[funcs, {x, -5, 5}]
   ];

n = 5
varlist = Table[Symbol[ToString[StringForm["a``", i]]], {i, 1, n}]
clauses = Sequence @@ Table[{{a, 1}, 0.1, 5}, {a, varlist}]
Activate[Inactive[Manipulate][Inactive[PlotSines][varlist], clauses]]
```

draws

[image]

Comment: This will fail if e,g, `a1 = 2;` was evaluate or any of `ai` have value.