# Functions defined with numbers

Tags: function-construction, core-language

If I have defined functions as "A1", "A2" ecc. then I have many function as A+number, can I define a For cycle to call these functions (they have all the same kind of arguments) once?

Something like

```
For[i<64, i == 0, i++, A"i"[]]
```

I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: `Table[ToExpression @ StringTemplate["A``[]"] @ i, {i, 64}]`. In general take a look at: [783](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478)

Comment: Why not define these functions as `A[1]`, `A[2]` etc.?

Comment: Thank you both, I have defined these functions as A[1] ecc... Now I am satisfied!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Symbol` function. For example:

```
For[i = 0, i < 64, i++, Symbol[StringTemplate["A``"]@i][]]
```

Perhaps it will be faster than `ToExpression`.
Also you can use auxiliary function:

```
A[i_] := A[i] = Symbol@StringTemplate["A``"]@i

For[i = 0, i < 64, i++, A[i][]]
```

Previously calculated `A[i_]` results (symbols) are "cached" by `A[i_] := A[i]=...`.

IMHO best way is to define array (or `SparseArray`) of functions. Then you can call functions directly by index without extra symbol lookup.