# How to block list of variable that is of string form?

Tags: scoping, meta-programming

For example, I have

```
varList={"a1","a2",...}
```

`a1`, `a2`,... are all variables, they maybe assigned values already.

What I want to do is temporarily `Block` all variables in `varList` for a segment of my code. This means equivalent to `Block[{a1,a2,...},other code]`.

So maybe a function `myBlock` similar to `Block`,

```
myBlock[varList,other code]
```

How to do this?

Comment: closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myBlock // ClearAll

myBlock // Attributes = {HoldAll};

  (*for a standardBlock syntax *)
myBlock[varList : {(_Symbol | _Set) ..}, code_] := Block[varList, code]


  (*for string spec hidden in a symbol *)
myBlock[varList_Symbol, code_] /; ValueQ[varList] := myBlock[Evaluate@varList, code]


  (* for list of string specs*)
myBlock[varList : {__String}, code_] := 
  Join @@ ToExpression[varList, StandardForm, Hold] /. 
  Hold[vars__] :> Block[{vars}, code]
```

---

```
a1 = 1

{ myBlock[{"a1"}, a1 = 2; a1], a1 }

{ myBlock[{a1}, a1 = 3; a1]  , a1 }

{ myBlock[{a1 = 4}, a1]      , a1 }

{ myList = {"a1"}
; myBlock[myList, a1 = 5; a1], a1 }

{ myList = {"a1 = 6", "a2"}
; myBlock[myList, a1]        , a1 }
```

> 1
>
> {2,1}
>
> {3,1}
>
> {4,1}
>
> {5,1}
>
> {6,1}

Comment: You could make use of the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable) attribute of [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression), e.g., ``ToExpression[varList,StandardForm,Hold]``

Comment: @CarlWoll +1 sure I could, If I only knew. All those years of mapping ;(

Comment: Thank you so much! Learned a lot. I took some time rereading Wagner's "power programming...", finally has some progress in understanding Hold stuff(which should be know years ago) , and came out my version as an answer. What is more, I actually struggled to construct a function let's call it `convert`, so that `Block[Evaluate@convert@varList,code]` will work. But I failed, so I thought maybe it is not possible for such `convert` function, what do you think? : )

Comment: @Kuba Oh, there is also string mix symbol case missing, though rare, but...

Comment: @Kuba I updated a unified version. Now it is fully settled down :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is enlightened by Kuba. Thanks.

**update**

By utilizing `RowBox` and the fact that `ToString` doesn't change string. I provide a unified version of `myBlock` with a single definition that is fully compatible with built-in `Block`, and at the same time support list of symbols in string form or a list of mixture of symbol and string form(currently not supported by Kuba's version).

```
ClearAll[myBlock];
SetAttributes[myBlock, HoldAll];
myBlock[varList_, code_] := 
  Module[{toStringWithHold, varStringList, holdVars},
   toStringWithHold = Function[x, ToString[Unevaluated[x]], {HoldAll}];
   varStringList = toStringWithHold /@ Unevaluated[varList];
   varStringList = 
    Flatten@StringSplit[Riffle[varStringList, ","], "=" -> "="];
   holdVars = 
    ToExpression[RowBox@Prepend[Append[varStringList, "}"], "{"], 
     StandardForm, Hold];
   holdVars /. Hold[x_] :> Block[x, code]];
```

It uses `RowBox` technique, also thanks to [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83129/4742)

So now take a look at below

```
a1 = 100;
a2 = 200;
{myBlock[{a1, a2}, a1 = 1; a2 = 2; {a1, a2}], {a1, a2}}
{myBlock[{"a1", "a2"}, a1 = 1; a2 = 2; {a1, a2}], {a1, a2}}
{myBlock[{"a1", a2}, a1 = 1; a2 = 2; {a1, a2}], {a1, a2}}
{myBlock[{"a1=1", a2 = 2}, {a1, a2}], {a1, a2}}
{varList = {"a1", "a2"}; myBlock[varList, a1 = 1; a2 = 2; {a1, a2}], {a1, a2}}
{varList = {"a1=1", "a2=2"}; myBlock[varList, {a1, a2}], {a1, a2}}
```

They all gives

```
{{1, 2}, {100, 200}}
```

Which means that `myBlock` correctly block variables, and doesn't affect global value.