# Symbol created in Module not seen outside of Module scope

Tags: scoping

I am using a function defined with a `Module[]`. In the `Module` I am creating a new variable name using a `Symbol[]` function. I would like to reuse the created symbol outside the function call, namely here: `varf` in the following lines of code:

```
f[a_] := Module[{var}, var = a; vart = 44; Symbol["var" <> "f"] = 3]
```

The function returns `3`, if I call `vart` I get `44`. If I call `var` I don't get value of `a`. If I call `varf` I get `varf`.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you noticed "Set::write: Tag Symbol in Symbol[varf] is Protected."? Anyway, take a look at [How to create symbols from strings and set values for them?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83129/5478)

Comment: Yes, that error popped out, but when I called Context[varf] I got Global for a response.

Comment: Because it was created when you called Context.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I replace all Symbol[] with RawBox[] and whenever I have a value assignment that I add a wrapper ToExpression@MakeBoxes[...]   around the assignment command?

Comment: I am suggesting that when you want to assign a value to a symbol generated from a string, then read the linked topic. If you should do this depends of your use case, it is usually better to use Indexed as opposed to symbol generation.