# How to make c[n_, x_, y_] := ToExpression["p" <> ToString[n]] = {x, y} work?

Tags: evaluation, assignment

I am trying to do the following:

```
c[n_, x_, y_] := ToExpression["p" <> ToString[n]] = {x, y}
```

That is: Evaluating `c[1,1,1]`, yields the assignment `p1={1,1}` but this is giving me the following error:

> Set::write: Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[p2] is Protected.

I have also tried:

```
c[n_, x_, y_] := Evaluate[ToExpression["p" <> ToString[n]] = {x, y}]
```

But it also doesn't work. How can I make this work?

Comment: ``Set`` has an attribute ``HoldFirst``, which means you have to manually evaluate the expression to get the symbol: ``c[n_, x_, y_] := Set[Evaluate@Symbol["p" <> ToString[n]], {x, y}]``

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/783/how-to-create-symbols-from-strings-and-set-values-for-them

Comment: This sounds like it might be an XY problem.  For example, would `c[n_,x_,y_]:=p[n]={x,y}` work for your purposes?

Comment: @evanb This works perfectly! Thanks! I wasn't aware I could do that.

Comment: Great!  Glad to help!

Answer (score 6):

I recommend that the construct `ToExpression["p" <> ToString[n]]` for variable names be avoided. It makes the resulting variable names more difficult to work with. It is much more flexible to use indexed variables. You can [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) the display of indexed variables in any desired manner.

```
ClearAll[c, p]

Format[p[n_]] := "p" <> ToString[n] (* or Subscript[p,n] *)

c[n_, x_, y_] := p[n] = {x, y}

c[#, x, y] & /@ Range[5];
```

The five `p` variables have been [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)

```
p /@ Range[7]

(* {{x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, "p6", "p7"} *)
```

Although displayed as `p6` and `p7`, they are stored as indexed variables

```
% // InputForm

(* {{x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, p[6], p[7]} *)
```

As indexed variables you can more readily work with a large number of them.

```
SeedRandom[1234];

Total[c[#, RandomInteger[100], RandomInteger[100]] & /@ Range[20]] === 
 Total[p /@ Range[20]]

(* True *)

p[2]

(* {32, 56} *)

c[2, 6, 7] (* or p[2] = {6, 7} *)

(* {6, 7} *)

p[2]

(* {6, 7} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at:

```
Attributes[Set]
{HoldFirst, Protected, SequenceHold}
```

The attribute "HoldFirst" prohibits the evaluation of "Symbol[..]" as you can see from:

[image: Symbol["p1"] = 1]

Therefore, you must force the evaluation of "Symbol" by:

```
Clear["p*", c]
c[n_, x_, y_] := (Evaluate[Symbol["p" <>ToString[n]]]) = {x, y}
c[1, 1, 1];
p1
(* {1, 1} *)
```

Comment: Actually this only works first time. Try calling `c[1, 1, 1]` from new cell again and you will get an error `Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 1.`