# How can I make 10 variables from a for loop?

Tags: variable-definitions, procedural-programming

I used a for loop to make 4 variables:

```
   For[i = 0, i < 4, i++,bi=0]
```

But when I write `b0` or `b1` it print its as b0 or b1 not `0` or `0`.

Comment: possible duplicate: [783](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478)

Comment: An alternative approach is to use Array[a, 10]. Now you have created 10 different a's that you can use as a[3] or a[7].

Comment: Mathematica is different from explicit programming (C, Python, etc.): in Mathematica there is no need for such explicit assignments. In this case, for example you could define `b[i_] = 0` to make every value zero (as a [pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html)), or you could restrict it to your values with `b[i_Integer /; 0 <= i < 4] = 0`. Please read an [introduction to the Wolfram language](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/).

Answer (score 6):

You might find it easier to do

```
For[i = 0, i < 4, i++,b[i]=0]

b[3] (* gives 0 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ToExpression`

```
For[i = 0, i < 4, i++, ToExpression["b" <> ToString[i] <> "=" <> ToString[i]]]
```

and now

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am not sure why you want to do the above, there could be better ways to solve the problem you are trying to solve if you explain the purpose of doing this.