# Assigning each string variable to the corresponding element from the list inside a loop

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to assign values from a list `l` to variables `g1`, `g2`, `g3`, ....

The list: `l=Table[(i^2-10*i)/2,{i,1,10}]`.I would like to assign `g1` to the first element of the list `l[[1]]` and so on using a loop.

`g1=l[[1]]`;
`g2=l[[2]]`;
`g3=l[[3]]`;
...

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

l = Table[(i^2 - 10*i)/2, {i, 1, 10}]

(*{-(9/2), -8, -(21/2), -12, -(25/2), -12, -(21/2), -8, -(9/
  2), 0}*)

Do[Symbol["g" <> ToString[i]] = l[[i]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Based on your last three questions, it appears that you're trying to do some computations with lists of things, and you think you need variables to represent each thing. Or something along those lines. Maybe if you just told us the problem you're trying to solve, we could give you good advice. I'm starting to feel bad about answering your specific questions, because they will ultimately lead you to bad programming practices.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/274713/7936

Comment: @lericr, thanks a lot! Yes, you're right, it's worth setting variables more obviously.

Comment: @evanb, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is very likely an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

I'd say the "correct" way is to avoid symbol construction through strings, and go with indices instead. Using a [delayed assignment](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html),

```
Clear[g];
g[i_Integer /; 1 <= i <= Length[l]] := l[[i]]
g[___] = Indeterminate;
```

or, if you don't care about error checking,

```
Clear[g];
g[i_] := l[[i]]
```

You can use `g[5]` instead of your `g5`, for example, without affecting calculations.

Comment: Thanks! But how to set such variables `g[5]` in a function `f`? I mean for example `f[g[5]_]:=g[5]^2`

Comment: Just say something like `f[x_]:=g[x]^2`?

Comment: Or, just `l^2`, even.

Comment: You need to learn more about what variables and patterns are. As @evanb says, define `f[x_] = x^2` and then call `f[g[5]]` because it will substitute the pattern `x_` with the argument `g[5]`. There is really no need to define a new function `f` for every variable you have.

Comment: @Roman, thanks!